# How do i get img-fluid to work in Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to make my images within my carousel responsive by adding the img-fluid tag to them but nothing is working. I've tried using !important. I've tried using block. I am not sure what is preventing the change. Any suggestions?

```
.container{
        
        font-size: 32px;
        font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
        position:relative;
        top: 150px;
        right:-15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        width: 1440px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        
      
  }
  
 
  
  .item{
      
      
        float:right;
      
     
      
  }
  


<div class="container">
```

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img class="image img-fluid" src="images/image-tanya.jpg" alt="Tanya" style="height:648px; width:648px;" ><div class="carousel-caption">  
  </div>
    </div>      

  <div class="item ">
    <img class="image img-fluid" src="images/image-john.jpg" alt="John" style="height:648px; width:648px;">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style="height:648px; width:648px;"` is the culprit

The styles defined by the `img-fluid` class are being overwritten by the inline styles on the `img` tags in the the HTML.  Inline styles always take precedence over those defined in style sheets. Try removing those inline styles and see what happens :)